# CakePHP 3, associated data being saved as new not updating?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

### UPDATE

As Requested, this is the `$this->request->data` thats form my forms,

```
'office' => 'LON-test33',
'phone' => '456456456',
'address' => [
    'addline1' => '1 test0009 st',
    'addline2' => 'p09987',
    'addline3' => 'test9999',
    'postcode' => 'p888',
    'country_id' => '226'
],
```

So the office, phone are part of my office table, the address is the whole address table.

I have also done a test, to see if it was something in the model, by just trying to update just the address table by suppling it an ID. Which works so I take it my model is fine. So I am thinking either something to do with the Office model or something wrong with my code?

Thanks,

---

So I am using CakePHP 3.0.something ....

I am trying to update my address which is associated data to the office table. However when I update the office, the address is saved as a whole new record? Not sure why?

Here is what I am doing so far,

```
$OfficeTable = TableRegistry::get('Offices');
$CurrentOffice = $OfficeTable->get($OfficeID);

$OfficeTable->patchEntity($CurrentOffice, $this->request->data, ['associated' => ['Addresses']]);

debug( $OfficeTable->save($CurrentOffice) );
```

Setting the `Associated` in the patchEntity seems to make no difference, the updated address is saved, but as a new record. This new records ID is then placed into the Office table in the 'address_id' field.

But why is it adding this 'new/edited' address as a new record and not updating the associated id record?

Now I have been reading the docs, and form what I understand, it will make a new record if it can not find the record? However, I have debugged the save call and on both the office and address there is a '[new]' set to false. So why update my office but make a new address when it is telling me its not new?

So to add, at the bottom of my debug call there is '[original]' which contains the old address id of the record it should of updated.

So what am I doing wrong?

**If I have not explained myself right (I am dyslexic), then please let me know or if anything is missing I can update - Thanks**

Comment: What does the request data that you are patching in look like?

Comment: @ndm Question as been updated.

Comment: Ok I have it working, but I am not sure this is the best way to do it. But adding,  'id' => true, to 'accessible' in my Address Entity, seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Depends... you seem to use a `Offices belongsTo Addresses` association, is that correct? And if that's the case, is there also a `Addresses hasMany Offices` association? It seems a little weird that you can edit the address together with the office when not using a `hasOne` association.

Comment: @ndm Yes that is right, my `code` OfficeTable  belongsTo Addresses `code` and my `code` AddressTable hasMany Offices `code` - I have not really played around with these from what CakePHP baked for me when I set up the site. My SQL knowledge is a little on the weak side, so are you saying my relationships are set up wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally there are two ways how you can solve this,

- either by passing the ID with the request data, which, as you've figured out requires the ID field to be [**set as accessible**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#mass-assignment) in the entity, so that it can be set in patching process
- or by making sure that the ID is already present in the entity that you are going to patch, for example by containing the association when retrieving the entity

  ```
  $CurrentOffice = $OfficeTable->get($OfficeID, [
      'contain' => [
          'Addresses'
      ]
  ]);
  ```

Personally I would recommend the latter method, as it has less possible pitfalls since you don't need to make the ID accessible. I'd recommed you have a read here: **[Preventing malicious users update data at add action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720021/preventing-malicious-users-update-data-at-add-action)**

That being said, the fact that you edit the address together with the office seems a little odd, as changing address details will "affect" all offices, so there's usually not really a need to edit both at the same time. However that's just a rather superficial concern, as I don't know your apps internals and requirements.

Comment: Sorry I was away for the last few days. Umm maybe, I have designed this database wrong then. Each office will have a title, phone etc and an addressID, which will link into the Address table. But one office will only ever have one address, so when the end user edits the office, they will need to edit that address. I made the address table this way for the possibly that the users may, at some stage, have an address linked to them. Was I wrong?

Comment: I will also add that, I am more or less being made to make each field on all the tables to accpect null data all the time, so that when a new office is saved, the only thing that would be made would be a new ID in my table.

Comment: Many thanks. Containing the Address table when I fetch my Office table works without any issues that I can see. I did think that I should be able to do this without making my ID accessible. And I was very unsure about doing so. Thanks again.